# Site NewsFeed Conversation box missing

Tags: site, newsfeed, sitefeed

Having this issue with my sharepoint site where the NewsFeed "Start a Conversation Box" doesn't appear. When logged in as administrator I can see the conversation box and post to the site.

But when logged in as my user account I'm unable to see the conversation box to post to the site or the posts from the administrator.

I'm quite confused about this because I went through all the permissions and my account is assigned contribute permissions but still nothing. Iv'e even made my account owner for testing purposes but im still unable to post to my site.

[EDIT] Logged in as Admin I can copy the Conversation link from the newsfeed and post it into my browser which will redirect to the message that was posted.(Please see image 2)[image: Image 2] However if I try to post the link into my browser where I am logged in as myself it will direct to " Sorry someone has deleted this conversation".(Please see image 3)[image: Image 3]

Answer (score 0):

This is normally due to permissions.

Check to see what permissions you have at site level (i do not think it is possible to change the news feed permissions).

Specifically check to see if your user has Write access.

Comment: Hey Roland,

My user is in a group on the site and that group has correct permissions to post(according to other blogs) and I'm still unable to view the "start a conversation box" to post. I am able to see the actual webpart but not the messages posted.